# Error converting a bash function to a csh alias

Tags: csh

I am writing a csh alias so that I can use the following bash function in my csh :

```
function up( )
{
    LIMIT=$1
    P=$PWD
    for ((i=1; i <= LIMIT; i++))
    do
        P=$P/..
    done
    cd $P
    export MPWD=$P
}
```

(I stole the above bash function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188162/what-is-the-most-useful-script-youve-written-for-everyday-life/188560#188560))

I have written this:

```
alias up 'set LIMIT=$1; set P=$PWD; set counter = LIMIT;  while[counter!=0] set counter = counter-1; P=$P/.. ; end cd $P; setenv MPWD=$P'
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
while[counter!=0]: No match.
P=/net/devstorage/home/rghosh/..: Command not found.
end: Too many arguments.
```

and my script is not working as intended. I have been reading up on csh from [here](http://faculty.plattsburgh.edu/jan.plaza/computing/help/tcsh.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure it’s even possible to do a `while` loop all on one line. 
But there are several fixable errors:

- `while[counter!=0]` should be `while ($counter != 1)`
  (note the spaces before and after the “`!=`”).
- `set counter = counter-1` should be `@ counter = $counter – 1`
  (note the spaces before and after the ‘`–`’).
- `P=$P/..` should be `set P=$P/..` –– or better yet, `set P="$P/.."` (in case `$P` contains space(s).
- Which reminds me, `set P=$PWD` should be `set P="$PWD"`, `cd $P` should be `cd "$P"`, and `setenv MPWD=$P` should be `setenv MPWD="$P"`, all for the same reason.
- And, if you do manage to get the `while` loop all on one line to work, you’re probably going to need a `;` after the `end`.

Comment: I had to write the while loop in a single line because I was getting a horde of errors while using the the next line facility using `/`

Comment: OK, but my point is: have you ever gotten a ‘while loop in a single line’ ***to work***?  If yes, please post an example; even if it’s something trivial like `mkdir –p foo/foo/foo; while { cd foo } pwd; end`.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple lines of code, aliases must be within single quotes, and each end of line must precede a backslash. The end of the last line must precede a single quote to delimit the end of the alias:

```
alias up 'set counter = \!$\
set p = "$cwd"\
while ( $counter >= 1 )\
@ counter = $counter - 1\
set p = "$p/.."\
end\
cd "$p"\
setenv mpwd "$p"'
```

If experiencing issues with the command editor/history, add `kill -INT $$` to the end of the alias.

By the way, variables set with `set` are better with the equal sign separated from the variable name and content; `setenv` doesn't require an equal sign; math functionality is provided by `@`; control structures make use of parentheses; use **$cwd** to print the current working directory; numbers are better tested with the greater than (>; >=) and less than (<; <=) operators; `\!$` denotes the last argument of the command.